# com.google.i18n.phonenumbers Bug?

Tags: java, internationalization

As far as I know BRAZIL COUNTRY CODE is +55

But this piece of code

```
mobilePhoneNumber = "+32495665962";
            isoCode = "BR";

            phoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.parse(mobilePhoneNumber, isoCode);
            isValid = phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
            phoneNumberType = phoneNumberUtil.getNumberType(phoneNumber);

            System.out.println ("phoneNumber ----- > " + phoneNumber);
            System.out.println ("isValid --------- > " + isValid);
            System.out.println ("phoneNumberType - > " + phoneNumberType);
```

gives me that number as valid !

```
phoneNumber ----- > Country Code: 32 National Number: 495665962
isValid --------- > true
phoneNumberType - > MOBILE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read the Javadoc](http://javadox.com/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/5.9/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> `defaultRegion` - region that we are expecting the number to be from. **This is only used if the number being parsed is not written in international format**. The country_code for the number in this case would be stored as that of the default region supplied. If the number is guaranteed to start with a '+' followed by the country calling code, then "ZZ" or null can be supplied.

Your input is in international form, so this parameter is not used.

Why would you expect the library to convert a phone number in Belgium to one in Brazil?

Answer (score 1):

`libphonenumber`'s `isValidNumber(...)` will return true if the number is valid anywhere. For instance, what you are entering is a valid Belgium number. I believe you are using it wrong. For what you want to do use `isValidNumberForRegion(Phonenumber.PhoneNumber number, String regionCode)`.

See https://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/8.5.0